# pyinstaller with matplotlib backend_wxagg and hashlib md5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

A colleague of mine is having an issue building a python app we're working on together.  We've been able to isolate the issue and replicate with the following code:

```
print "before import"
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg
print "after import"
```

We're both working on the same shared computer (RHEL 6.6), using Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6, matplotlib 1.4.2, and pyinstaller 3.2.

Here's where the fun begins:

- We are both able to run this from source through `python test.py`, and it behaves exactly as expected.
- I'm able to generate an executable using `pyinstaller test.py`, and aside from a missing .so that it complains about, everything runs fine.
- If my colleague attempts `pyinstaller test.py`, the executable is generated without complaint, but we when we try to run it we get the following error message.

Error:

```
[username@machine test]$ ./test
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
  File "hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
before import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/u/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.2-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib/backends/backend_wxagg.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/u/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.2-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib/figure.py", line 38, in <module>
  File "/u/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.2-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "/u/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.2-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib/contour.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "/u/username/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.2-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 49, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name md5
Failed to execute script test
```

Obviously, something is different in how our environments are setup, and something isn't getting pulled along by pyinstaller.  I just can't figure out what it is!  We've tried adding hashlib and md5 both as hidden-imports, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to build a frozen binary with cx_Freeze. After trying a lot of desperate hacks, like patching `hashlib.py`, I finally got rid of the error message by excluding `hashlib` altogether.

In cx_Freeze it looks like:

```
…
excludes = ["collections.abc", "tcl", "tk", "OpenGL", "scipy", "hashlib"]

build_options = {
    "packages": packages,
    "includes": includes,
    "include_files": include_files,
    "excludes": excludes, }
…
setup(name=…,
  version=…,
  description=…,
  options=dict(build_exe=build_options,
               install_exe=install_options),
  executables=executables)
```

I suppose that `pyinstaller` also offers options to exclude libraries.

I'm now struggling with other errors, related to conflicting numpy versions, so I cannot 100% confirm that the disapperance of the error indicates that the problem is solved.